# How to encode strings in ColdFusion excluding the "dot"

Tags: encoding, coldfusion, character-encoding, urlencode, coldfusion-9

I am looking for a way to encode strings with ColdFusion but excluding the ".".
This is what I have tried so far:

```
<!--- Test area --->
<cfset str="ChrisTilghmanFirstFlash.Eflv">
<cfset str1="Chris Tilghman First Flash.Eflv">
<cfset str2="Chris-Tilghman First_Flash.Eflv">
<cfset enc1 = urlEncodedFormat(str,"utf-8" )>
<cfset enc2 = urlEncodedFormat(str1,"utf-8")>
<cfset enc3 = urlEncodedFormat(str2,"utf-8")>
<cfoutput>#enc1#</cfoutput><br>
<cfoutput>#enc2#</cfoutput><br>
<cfoutput>#enc3#</cfoutput><br>
<!--- END test area --->
```

The urlEncode utf-8 other encodes the "dot", "-" and "_" characters too. How do I prevent this scenario?

Comment: Is that really the solution you need? From what I'm reading it sounds more like you only want to encode the space character. `replace(str," ","%20","all")` will suffice in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One answer can be found in [this thread](http://web.archive.org/web/20110102120715/http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_URL_encoding_to_RFC_3986-17970.html), which

> Use[s] ColdFusion's ReplaceList() function to "correct" the errors made
>   by URLEncodedFormat() to produce an RFC 3986 compliant URL encoded
>   string.

**Code:**

```
<cfset string = replacelist(urlencodedformat(string), "%2D,%2E,%5F,%7E", "-,.,_,~")>
```

Answer (score 3):

This will solve it for you:-

```
<cfset str="ChrisTilghmanFirstFlash.Eflv">
<cfset str1="Chris Tilghman First Flash.Eflv">
<cfset str2="Chris-Tilghman First_Flash.Eflv">
<cfset enc1 = urlEncodedFormat(str,"utf-8" )>
<cfset enc2 = urlEncodedFormat(str1,"utf-8")>
<cfset enc3 = urlEncodedFormat(str2,"utf-8")>
<cfoutput>#replace(enc1, "%2E", ".", "ALL")#</cfoutput><br>
<cfoutput>#replace(enc2, "%2E", ".", "ALL")#</cfoutput><br>
<cfoutput>#replace(enc3, "%2E", ".", "ALL")#</cfoutput><br>
```

Comment: Um looking for a generic way . If there are other special characters how may handle the issue?

Comment: Ok well you need to be more clear about what you want then. Because urlEncodedFormat is for encoding special characters and so is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. By reading your question I assume you want to encode everything but a full stop. What are you actual requirements?

Comment: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_URL_encoding_to_RFC_3986-17970.html this may help for everyone . Thank you

Comment: You should post this as the answer for others!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the dot as a list separator and encode each item in the list separately. Something like this:

```
<cfset enc1="">
<cfloop list="#str#" index="i" delimiter=".">
  <cfset listAppend(enc1,urlEncodedFormat(i,"utf-8"),".")>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: I don't have an issue with the downvote(s), but could someone perhaps clue me in on what is wrong with my solution?

Comment: This approach is OK, though I would make it more flexible to support other characters that need to be excluded: split string as list, encode parts, merge back.

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for comments ...)

I came across this thread while trying to implement [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) encoding. In case you are using the newer [encodeForURL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) function (instead of [urlEncodedFormat](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforurl.html)) it gets you a little closer, but still requires a few tweaks.

According to RFC 3986:

- Unreserved characters that should *not* be escaped:
  `ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~" /`
- Spaces should be encoded as `%20` instead of `+`
- Reserved characters that should be escaped include: `: / ? ## [ ] @ ! $ & ' ( ) * + , ; =`

To make the results of EncodeForURL compatible:

- Force encoding of asterisk "*" (reserved character)
- Reverse the encoding of tilde "~" (should *not* be encoded).
- Change space encoding from "+" to "%20":

**Code:**

```
encodedText = encodeForURL("space period.asterisk*");
encodedText = replaceList( encodedText , "%7E,+,*", "~,%20,%2A");
```